# Proving that $\{f\in C([0,1]):|f(1)|\geq 2\}$ is closed in $C([0,1])$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that $$\{ f \in C([0,1]): |f(1)| \ge 2 \}$$ is closed as a subset of the metric space $\left( C([0,1]), d_C\right)$, where $$d_C (f,g):=\max_{x \in [0,1]} \left| f(x) -g(x) \right|.$$

I attempted to show that the complement is open but am unsure how to proceed.

**What I've tried is:** Let $U$ be the original set and $V$ be the complement of $U$. Showing that $V$ is open proves that $U$ is closed. That is, for all $f\in C([0,1])$, find $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon<2-|f(1)|$. Since $f$ is continuous, $g=f/2$ must also be in $C([0,1])$. Take $\epsilon=1-g$, then for all $f$ we can find $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon<2-|f(1)|$. But this really doesn't sound right, since it doesn't take into account the metric at all.

Answer (score 1):

Take a convergent sequence $f_n \to f \in C([0,1])$ and show that the limit belongs to your set. Note that the convergence using the metric you have implies uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. The map $\phi:C([0,1])\to\mathbb{K}$ given by $\phi(f):=f(1)$ is continuous and $$\{f\in C([0,1]):|f(1)|\geq 2\}=\phi^{-1}(\{x\in\mathbb{K}:|x|\geq 2\})$$ is closed since $\{x\in\mathbb{K}:|x|\geq 2\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: $\pji$ is continuous uses the metric: $|\phi(f)-\phi(g)|= |f(1)-g(1)| \le d_C(f,g)$ so $\phi$ is even a contraction.